# Dinner: Small group

Tags: phrase-requests

I would like to invite several people to a dinner. In the invitation, I want to emphasize that this is a smaller group, and not everyone from work is invited.

I was thinking about "dinner in small group", "smaller circle", "intimate environment", but these all sound odd. This is going to be a fancy place and I don't want to make it sound like I'm saving money, or come on romantically. How could I phrase it?

Comment: *Please join me and a few other friends for dinner at ...*